# how to read data from a FileStream and add them to a queue in midwhile

Tags: c#, tcp, tcpclient

i have a client as below

```
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 13000);
        var stream = client.GetStream();
        byte[] buff = new byte[1024];

        List<byte> bytequeue = new List<byte>();

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        int count = 0;
        do
        {
            count = stream.Read(buff, 0, 1024);
            ms.Write(buff, 0, count);
            
        } while (stream.CanRead && count > 0);

        stream.Flush();
        client.Close();
```

and i would like to add the byte just read inside the while loop to a queue (list of byte)

Answer (score 0):

Using linq you probably can do this:

```
bytequeue = bytequeue.Concat(buff.ToList());
```

Both ToList and Concat are Linq functions, they actually do what their names say.
I did not write a complete test application. See also

https://www.techiedelight.com/convert-array-to-list-csharp/